# what does "slip-fashion" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *Dune* (2021), a planetologist and imperial judge Dr. Liet-Kynes speaks to Paul:

> Dr. Liet-Kynes: Your desert boots are fitted **slip-fashion** at the
> ankles.

what does "slip-fashion" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**slip-fashion** is not a common English term when referring to the fit of boots. I believe this is lingo that the author of Dune came up with. Its meaning is somewhat up to your interpretation. What the author meant by this has been discussed elsewhere, like in this Reddit [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/dune/comments/ooioqc/is_slipfashion_a_well_known_way_to_wear_boots/).

Comment: I'd say that almost certainly Frank Herbert came up with the collocation himself - as much to allude to the "exotic, other-worldly, alien" context of the narrative itself as for the *meaning*. Google Books has no instances of the sequence ***fitted slip fashion*** except in the *Dune* books, and the variant ***fastened slip-fashion*** (which sounds slightly more "idiomatic" to my ear) doesn't occur at all. You can "decode" the usage, but it doesn't really have any intrinsic meaning other than whatever the reader assumes when he first encounters it.